# drools condition with different class

Tags: java, drools, drools-guvnor

I am learning drools and what I attempt to do was to write condition for the checks

For example:

There are 3 Pojo class. Hotel, Customer, Payment.

```
Hotel:
int id
int roomSize;
...getter/setter

Customers:
int id
String name
int groupSize
...getter/setter

Payment:
int id
int amount
...getter/setter
```

What I want is to write rules for checking mixed class like

```
if(hotel.roomSize > customer.groupSize && hotel.count > 3 && customer.groupSize == 1) {
    payment.setAmount(50);
} else {
    payment.setAmount((hotel.roomSize - custmer.groupSize) * 65)
}
------------------------
rule "some checks"
    when
        h : Hotel(h.roomCount < 3)
        c : Customer(c.groupSize == 1)

    then
        System.out.println(....);
end
```

and on the side doubt there is no else in the rules so do I have to write two rules for every condition? 
such as: `h.roomSize < 3 and another rule for h.roomSize > 3`?

```
what I want to achieve is to have a set of rules in sequence like
rule a:
rule b:
rule c:
rule d:
and if b fails dont execute c and d.
```

Comment: I don't see how comparing `h < c` ("Hotel less than Customer") should ever make any sense. - Yes, basically you have to provide a rule for each set of conditions, although there are techniques that may reduce the amount of rule code to hande the "else" situation.

Comment: what i meant by h < c is I want to merge the above two statement into one single statement. sorry it was a typo. I want to do this because i need it to achieve a sequence

Comment: The fundamental misunderstanding is that rules should be "in a sequence". If statements are in a sequence, rules are not. - Perhaps you can manage to specify the attributes of class Hotel in a coherent way, avoiding the confusion resulting from roomSize, count and roomCount. - Examples for writing simple rules can be found in the examples that come with the Drools distribution. Also, make sure to study the Drools documentation.